# WORDPRESS permalinks and page store

Tags: wordpress, redirect, permalinks, oscommerce

I have wordpress installed on my website.
On that site, under a subfolder i have oscommerce system installed as online commerce store.

I activated permalinks on my wordpress, But now everytime i try to reach the store administration i get page not found in the wordpress.

If i'll disable the permalink i can gain access again, can you please help?

Thanks as always,
Danny

Comment: You might try the wordpress section: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you using custom Permalink? If so can you please post the link structure you are trying to use?

Or try this as custom  /%postname%/